# Centering a <object> tag inside a <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of a beginner using CSS3 and I'm trying to center a li tag that contains a SVG object.

I want the SVG object to appear centered while the other li tags float to the left and right.

Also, the SVG object is bigger than the other li, I'd like to align all the li so the bottom of the SVG is at the same height as the other li.

Any tips on how to do that ?

Thanks !

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

 .container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

ul li:first-child {
    float: left;
}

ul li.svg {
    float: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Title</li>
        <li class="svg"><object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://la-cascade.io/content/images/2015/06/kiwi.svg" width="20%"></object></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `center` isn't a valid value for `float`.

Comment: Welcome (back?) on SO, Yassine :)
Do you want 1/ 3 columns made of `li` with the SVG occupying the center one and half of other li on left, half on right 2/ Height of center column equals to height of left and/or right column? #1 may work with floats (on li except the one with SVG!) but #2 is a job for Flexbox...

Answer (score 1):

How about targeting the object #svg ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a `text-align: center;` for the containing `li` tag. Works in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to take off the SVG object and it looks like I can't even get the li tag to be centered:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

 .container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

ul li:first-child {
    float: left;
}

ul li.svg {
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Title</li>
        <li class="svg">Example</li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can simply add this code to your css

```
ul li.svg {
    text-align: center;
}
```

very simple . but i seen you use incorrect value for "float"

```
float:center ;
```

in css float can be

```
float:right;
```

or

```
float :left;
```

hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try with "title" (the first item) floating on left and all generic items on right, due to a margin-left as wide as 2 columns.
Columns have similar but not equal heights by fixing `line-height` to 1.5 and a multiple of latter. That means you must know the number of items to set height of title with this quick solution.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/ORqQoo

Note on semantics: a *title* should be a `h1-h6` element just before this list. If you had previously on your page a h1, than it would be a h2 followed by that list.

```css
/* (Codepen normalize and Autoprefixer are ON) */
 .container {
position: relative;
background-color: red;
min-height: 200px;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  width: 33.33%;
}
li:nth-child(n+3) {
  margin-left: 66.67%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}
li:first-child {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4.5;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: tomato;
}
li.svg {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Title</li>
        <li class="svg"><object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://la-cascade.io/content/images/2015/06/kiwi.svg" width="20%"></object></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```